bootstrap.yml not loaded at microservice startup
For some reason bootstrap.yml is ignored when I run this microservice. I think I've got all the necessary things in my pom:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.7</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>
    <groupId>my.whatever</groupId>
    <artifactId>whatever-service</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>${project.artifactId}</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <spring-boot.version>3.2.7</spring-boot.version>
        <spring.cloud.version>2023.0.2</spring.cloud.version>
    </properties>
    
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>


    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    
</project>


my bootstrap.yml is in /src/main/resources and contains
spring:
  application:
    name: whatever-service
  cloud:
    config:
      uri: http://localhost:8888

but when I start the ms I don't see him trying to fetch the config. I mean I don't see the following line:
service_1 | 2024-08-01T07:43:49.514Z  INFO 1 --- [service_1] [main] c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator : Fetching config from server at : http://localhost:8888

Another thing, when I simply give mvn clean install  it gets to the testing phase so it starts the application context and there I actually see the above line...
I think it's because of the annotation @SpringBootTest which inherits @BootstrapWith which I think forces the bootstrap.yml loading hence I see the line.]]
EDIT
I've gone deeper into the problem and it seems that the bootstrap.yml is not being copied to the docker image. To build I'm using this:
<plugin>
                <groupId>io.fabric8</groupId>
                <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${docker.maven-plugin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>build-image</id>
                        <phase>install</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>build</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>push-image</id>
                        <phase>deploy</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>push</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <pushRegistry>localhost:5000</pushRegistry>
                    <images>
                        <image>
                            <name>${project.name}:${project.version}</name>
                            <build>
                                <dockerFile>${project.basedir}/Dockerfile</dockerFile>
                                <args>
                                    <VERSION>${project.version}</VERSION>
                                </args>
                            </build>
                        </image>
                    </images>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

Dockerfile
# Build phase.
FROM maven:3.9.8-eclipse-temurin-17 as build
WORKDIR /data
COPY ./ /data
RUN mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true

# Deploy phase.
FROM eclipse-temurin:17.0.5_8-jdk-alpine
ARG VERSION
COPY --from=build /data/target/whatever-service-$VERSION.jar /app/app.jar
EXPOSE 8081
WORKDIR /app
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "app.jar"]

mvn clean install -DskipTests

I've also tried adding COPY src/main/resources/bootstrap.yml /app/bootstrap.yml to the Dockerfile but nothing. When I
docker run -it --entrypoint sh whatever-service:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
jar tf app.jar | grep bootstrap.yml

there is no bootstrap!
EDIT 2: other plugins + versions
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <spring-boot.version>3.2.7</spring-boot.version>
        <spring.cloud.version>2023.0.2</spring.cloud.version>
        <junit.bom.version>5.10.1</junit.bom.version>
        <openapi.version>2.5.0</openapi.version>
        <docker.maven-plugin.version>0.44.0</docker.maven-plugin.version>
    </properties>


<plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>build-info</goal>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                    <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-deploy</id>
                        <phase>none</phase> <!-- Disabilita il deploy standard -->
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>


I think it's because of the annotation @SpringBootTest which inherits @BootstrapWith which I think forces the bootstrap.yml loading hence I see the line.. It has nothing to do with that. How are you running this, how are you creating tjhe jar file etc.

Yeah, youre right. Unfortunately SO doesn't like too much code in questions. I shall edit now with more context and details @M.Deinum

At first glance your COPY comand is wrong that should read something like COPY ./src ./src you are already in the /data directory because you set that with WORKDIR. I would also assume you have the spring-boot-maven-plugin configured next to all the other things?

yes @M.Deinum, I've added EDIT 2 to the question

The fact that you have many plugins makes me wonder what you have more in there. You shouldn't need the compiler plugin nor the deploy plugin. I also wonder if this works at all, as you are running docker from maven inside docker. But as stated before your COPY looks weird I would fix that to start with.
